# Send two request simultaneously 1st request with C# WebClient and 2nd request with Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net

hey guys,
i have a page in asp.net c#, in that im doin' some video upload functionality, so my video upload code is in `Page_Load()` method and i'm using `WebClient` to upload a video file.
and i have a `animated gif` image on page

Now the problem is when `Page_Load()` method is called my files getting uploaded using WebClient, while that time the Page is not yet render, so i get a blank page.. i want that `gif` image get animated while uploading is goin' on...

**Note:** i have to use `WebClient's UploadFile()` method only.

So i was thinking is there any way that i can run my Upload functionality in new thread and let the page be Rendered.. or can ajax be helpfull in this scenario ??

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   UploadFile();//this method actually calls an API which uses WebClient to upload file
}
```

Another problem is to get a track of upload, that API gives a `url` which sends json response saying how much percent upload completed, so i also what to send request to this upload tracking `url` while my Uploading is goin' on simultaneously..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **asynchronous pages**:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/magazine/cc163725(en-us).aspx

Comment: that link was very helpfull indeed.. just now i tried that asynchronous page but my gif image is still not geting displayed..m confused a bit.. coz in this method `IAsyncResult BeginAsyncOperation (object sender, EventArgs e, 
        AsyncCallback cb, object state)
    {
        
    }` i have nothing to return